# Diretórios em c#

Tags: c#

Tenho vários ficheiros .Sql neste diretório: `C:\Users\anacarvalho\Desktop\Teste` como faço para ir buscar todos esses ficheiros?

Comment: Você pretende listar todos os scripts dentro do caminho?

Comment: sim é listar, mas que ao mesmo tempo corra em c#.

Comment: eu criei uma base de dados, onde coloco os caminhos dos ficheiros completos que eu quero. e depois em c# pus a correr e ele foi buscar esses ficheiros todos.Mas agora quero que em vez de colocar  o caminho todo, escrever apenas a pasta e ele ir buscar todos os ficheiros dentro dessa pasta

Comment: Ainda estou a testar! Já digo alguma coisa

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Utilize o Metodo *[Directory.GetFiles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/07wt70x2(v=vs.110).aspx)* com a opção de busca em todos diretorios

```
var Arquivos= Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Users\anacarvalho ", "*.sql", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

Answer (score 0):

Para quem quiser saber como eu resolvi o problema é o seguinte :

```
 string path = "C:\Users\anacarvalho\Desktop\Teste"; 
        string[] sqlFilesLocation = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.sql", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```